# Android app resolution gets messed up when locked and unlocked

Tags: bug, android-app

When I lock my phone (Note 4 running Android 6.0.1) and unlock it awhile later, often, everything will have become huge:

> [image: large texts]

To fix it, you just need to restart the app, but it's kind of annoying.

I can't reliably reproduce it. It's just something that happens at least once a day. I'm guessing it has to do with leaving the app open when I lock/sleep my phone since it only happens when the app is the first thing to open when I wake it.

The app is version 1.0.89.